# How to calm down TypeScript compiler?

Tags: typescript

Seems that `TypeScript` is oriented on Microsoft understanding of DOM and JS. What happens if I don't care about IE an Edge? I have problems with TypeScript...

For example. `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` returns object with `x` and `y` properties - in all browsers except IE and Edge (see notes [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect)).

So I have [compilation error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0D%0Alet%20rect%20%3D%20button.getBoundingClientRect()%3B%0D%0Alet%20xCoord%20%3D%20rect.x%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(xCoord)%3B) `TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'ClientRect | DOMRect'.`

Can I convince the compiler not to worry about this?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `left` property instead?

Comment: Why not just cast it to `DOMRect`? Eg: `let rect = button.getBoundingClientRect() as DOMRect;`

Comment: @MattMcCutchen You are right. I can use it. But I described this situation as an example. [I work in chrome and don't need to support IE. In console I see that `getBoundingClientRect()` returns object with `x` and `y` and will be happy to use it without getting warnings and errors ]

Comment: @CRice It helps! Can you please explain it? The error was `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'ClientRect | DOMRect'` So why does it helps to define it as `DOMRect`?

Comment: `ClientRect` is the half of that union that doesn't have an `x` and `y`. So you can just assert that instead of `rect` being one of either `ClientRect` or `DOMRect`, it is just `DOMRect`, which does have those properties.

Comment: @CRice I thought that `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'ClientRect | DOMRect'` means that property `x` doesn't  exist neither on `ClientRect` neither on `DOMRect`.

Comment: Not quite, it means that `x` doesn't exist on *one or the other or both*. In this case it is only `ClientRect` that lacks it. Typescript will actually tell you if this is the case, if you inspect the error in your playground closely, you'll see it goes on to say: `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'ClientRect'.`, meaning that is the only part of the union which lacks it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When TypeScript infers the type of a variable as `A | B` it actually means that it does only know the variable to be of type `A` or `B` (or something which is assignable to at least one of those).
Consequently when accessing a variable with such a type it only allows to access properties which are available in both types, as in either case they are present but others may be absent.

On the other hand a variable of type `A & B` is guaranteed to be of type `A` *and* of type `B`. Therefore the union of all properties you can find in `A` and `B` is available.

In your case TypeScript is actually friendly and doesn't hide the fact that in some circumstances `x` and `y` might be unavailable. But if you are sure they are, i.e. if you know that your rectangle is a proper [`DOMRect`](https://www.w3.org/TR/geometry-1/#dom-domrect) (or `DOMRectReadOnly`) you may just cast the variable to it:

```
const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect() as DOMRect;
```

If you are less sure, a concept named [type guards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html) might help you to avoid unchecked casts by enabling you to support TypeScript's type inference through providing code doing actual runtime checks.

```
if ('x' in rect) {
    // x is unique to DOMRect (ClientRect does not have it)
    // hence TS now knows rect is of type DOMRect.
    ...
}
```

For reference: On Microsoft's TypeScript project on Github you can find the [full DOM API types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts).

Answer (score 2):

One way around this problem would be to take advantage of [interface merging.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

```
interface ClientRect {
    x: number;
}

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
document.body.appendChild(button);
let rect = button.getBoundingClientRect();
let xCoord = rect.x; // no error!
console.log(xCoord);
```

TypeScript will merge together two interfaces with the same name, giving `ClientRect` an x property.